# Oracle sql create agenda

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with interval dates and times. Can i create a full list with this data?

Table example:

```
Start_Date, End_Date,    Start_Time, End_Time, Interval
01-jun-2021 02-jun-2021  08:00       10:00     30
03-jun-2021 04-jun-2021  10:00       12:00     15
```

Result:

```
01-jun-2021 08:00
01-jun-2021 08:30
01-jun-2021 09:00
01-jun-2021 09:30
02-jun-2021 08:00
02-jun-2021 08:30
02-jun-2021 09:00
02-jun-2021 09:30
03-jun-2021 10:00
03-jun-2021 10:15
03-jun-2021 10:30
03-jun-2021 11:00
03-jun-2021 11:15
03-jun-2021 11:30
03-jun-2021 11:45
04-jun-2021 10:00
04-jun-2021 10:15
04-jun-2021 10:30
04-jun-2021 11:00
04-jun-2021 11:15
04-jun-2021 11:30
04-jun-2021 11:45
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your table design is flawed. In oracle the data type DATE is actually date _and_time.  I don't know what data types you are acutally using, but you only need two columns:  START_DATE_TIME and END_DATE_TIME, both as data type DATE.

Comment: Your expected result doesn't include 10:45 for either day in the second half; is that just a mistake in posting, or intentional and there is some logic you left out? (I don't really see the separate start/end time columns as a problem here, incidentally - they could be combined but this makes it clearer that you only want those hours each day in the range. I would have a check constraint to make sure the dates are at midnight though, to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a handy place to use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte (start_date, end_date, interval) as (
      select to_date(start_date||start_time, 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI'), to_date(end_date||end_time, 'DD-Mon-YYYYHH24:MI'), interval
      from t
      union all
      select cte.start_date + cte.interval * interval '1' minute, end_date, interval
      from cte
      where cte.start_date < end_date
     )
select cast(start_date as timestamp)
from cte
order by start_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04ad0ca176dda86f1d685bfc7b5408a0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE, but the logic has to skip to the next day when you reach the end time; so this works:

```
with rcte (date_time, end_date, start_int, end_int, step_int) as (
  select
    start_date + to_dsinterval('0 ' || start_time || ':00'),
    end_date,
    to_dsinterval('0 ' || start_time || ':00'),
    to_dsinterval('0 ' || end_time || ':00'),
    interval * interval '1' minute
  from your_table
  union all
  select
    case
      when date_time + step_int < trunc(date_time) + end_int
      then date_time + step_int
      else trunc(date_time) + interval '1' day + start_int
    end,
    end_date,
    start_int,
    end_int,
    step_int
  from rcte
  where date_time + step_int < end_date + end_int
)
select date_time
from rcte
order by date_time
```

```
DATE_TIME
-------------------
2021-06-01 08:00:00
2021-06-01 08:30:00
2021-06-01 09:00:00
2021-06-01 09:30:00
2021-06-02 08:00:00
2021-06-02 08:30:00
2021-06-02 09:00:00
2021-06-02 09:30:00
2021-06-03 10:00:00
2021-06-03 10:15:00
2021-06-03 10:30:00
2021-06-03 10:45:00
2021-06-03 11:00:00
2021-06-03 11:15:00
2021-06-03 11:30:00
2021-06-03 11:45:00
2021-06-04 10:00:00
2021-06-04 10:15:00
2021-06-04 10:30:00
2021-06-04 10:45:00
2021-06-04 11:00:00
2021-06-04 11:15:00
2021-06-04 11:30:00
2021-06-04 11:45:00
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c772ef3669584a317538e293b7c3461b) showing the anchor member including converting the times and interval to real day to second intervals types for later use; the anchor and recursive members with all the intermediate columns; and finally just this version with a single column.

You can format the resulting date value however you want, of course.